# CNTK gather operation on dynamic axes

Tags: python, numpy, cntk

I am running a simple neural network using CNTK on Python but I want to print out a custom metric during training to monitor how the learning process improves this particular metric.

The output of the neural network is 202 points in 3D with x, y and z components (in my setup, this is a vector of 606 points with the x, y, and z components adjacent to one another, refer to the example). What I want to monitor during training is the value of the predicted y-component's difference from the target.

This is an example of what an output could look like:

```
              #x0    y0    z0    x1    y1    z1    ...  x202  y202  z202
predictions = [1.56, 2.34, 1.33, 3.24, 2.33, 1.97, ..., 0.97, 1.43, 5.86]
target =      [1.42, 2.20, 1.00, 2.99, 3.25, 1.97, ..., 0.52, 1.22, 4.99]
```

In `numpy`, I can easily get the y-components via fancy indexing:

```
y_components = predictions[1::3]
# [2.34, 2.33, ..., 1.43]
```

However, CNTK does not deal with this out-of-the-box and so I will have to use a provided CNTK operation; one that I found notable was `cntk.gather` which takes as arguments the predictions and a mask array of the indices of the values that I need. So I created a constant value as follows:

```
y_component_idx = C.constant(np.arange(1, 606, 3), dtype=np.int)
```

From this I should be able to calculate the metric with just the y-components with the following code:

```
c_X = C.input_variable((18,), np.float32)
c_Y = C.input_variable((606,), np.float32)
neural_net = Sequential([
    Dense(1000, activation=C.tanh),
    Dense(606)
])
predictions = neural_net(c_X)

y_component_idx = C.constant(np.arange(1, 606, 3), dtype=np.int)
y_pred_components = C.gather(predictions, y_component_idx)
y_targ_components = C.gather(c_Y, y_component_idx)
mse = C.reduce_mean(C.squared_error(predictions, c_Y))
metric = C.reduce_mean(C.less(C.abs(y_pred_components - y_targ_components), [0.1]))

params = [sgd(predictions.parameters, lr=0.01)]
trainer = C.Trainer(predictions, criterion=[mse, metric],
                    parameter_learners=params,
                    progress_writers=progress_printer)

for i in range(1000):
    # X_train and Y_train have sizes (1000, 18) and (1000, 606) respectively
    trainer.train_minibatch({c_X: X_train, c_Y: Y_train})
```

During runtime, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Gather operation's right operand doesn't expect to have dynamic axis
```

I have tried creating a constant mask array equal to the size of the batch but the same error appears. How do I formulate the `cntk.gather` operation so that it supports dynamic axes?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of gather cannot have any dynamic axis. It is a tensor of values. So You can unpack_batch/to_batch before and after gather to achieve that.

Answer [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2646).